How do I merge multiple dataframes and sum common values into column
I have many dataframe like:
df1                  df2                  and so on...
gene | counts        gene | counts   
KRAS    136          KRAS   96
DNAH5    3           DNAH5   4
TP53    105          TP53   20

I want to merge them and sum the column 'counts' so I end with only one dataframe
merged_df
gene | counts
KRAS    232       
DNAH5    7    
TP53    125 

I have tried to use pd.merge but it only accepts 2 dataframes at once, I have 14 dataframes. I used pd.concat for multiple dataframes but can't sum them after.

Indeed, pd.merge only merges 2 dataframes. But pd.join can join many, if they have the same index:
# Some example data. Note the None in `df3`. We want our code to handle that well.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'gene': ['KRAS', 'DNAH5', 'TP53'], 'counts': [136, 3, 105]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'gene': ['KRAS', 'DNAH5', 'TP53'], 'counts': [96, 4, 20]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'gene': ['KRAS', 'DNAH5', 'TP53'], 'counts': [1000, None, 3000]})
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

# We need the same index for the pd.DataFrame.join to work
dfs = [df.set_index('gene') for df in dfs]

# All the non-index columns need unique names, so chanding `columns` to `columns_0`, `columns_1`
dfs = [df.rename(columns={'counts': f'counts_{i}'}) for i, df in enumerate(dfs)]

# Actual join. We are joining first with the rest
df = dfs[0].join(dfs[1:], how='outer')

# Since we don't have any other data, we can just sum all columns.
df.sum(1)

This prints:
gene
KRAS     1232.0
DNAH5       7.0
TP53     3125.0


it worked, thank you!!

You can try this :
dataframes = [df1, df2, df3] # Add your dataframes here
concatenated_df = pd.concat(dataframes)
result_df = concatenated_df .groupby('gene', as_index=False).sum()


Avoiding the need for df.groupby (as here) or renaming columns (as here):

Use a list comprehension to apply df.set_index to each df
Pass the list to pd.concat with axis=1
Apply df.sum on axis=1 and df.reset_index

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'gene': ['KRAS', 'DNAH5', 'TP53'], 'counts': [136, 3, 105]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'gene': ['KRAS', 'DNAH5', 'TP53'], 'counts': [96, 4, 20]})

dfs = [df1, df2]

out = (
    pd.concat([df.set_index('gene') for df in dfs], axis=1)
    .sum(axis=1)
    .reset_index(name='counts')
)

Output:
    gene  counts
0   KRAS     232
1  DNAH5       7
2   TP53     125


You probably want to use the df.groupby() function in the end.
Here is how you do it:
First you df = df.concat([df1, df2, df3...]) your dataframes, so you end up with one big dataframe.
After that you need to use df = df.group_by('gene').sum().reset_index()
Basically you group all the rows based on the unique 'gene' column and then sum up all the 'counts' values for each 'gene'.
Reset index just converts the grouped 'gene' values back into regular column.
You can try running each command one-by-one to understand what's happening.
